# Copy only updated files, delete removed once and compress updated files

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

https://www.mehr-schulferien.de hosts some 100,000 webpages. For performance reasons they are not delivered from the actual web application but from a static mirror. This mirror gets generated on every 1st of a month. It's done by running `wget -m`. Followed by compressing all the files with gzip and brotli. Because this is a very old and slow server that process takes nearly two days.

I'd like to optimize the process. Less then 10% of the pages actually get new content every month. Some are deleted all together. So there is no need to compress all of them which takes most of the time.

Here is a simplified example (the actual one has subdirectories and obviously more files). In the `current` directory are all files from the `20190101` release and all those files are compressed with gzip and brotli. The `20190201` release removes the `b.html` file and changes the `a.html` file.

```
├── current
│   ├── a.html
│   ├── a.html.br
│   ├── a.html.gz
│   ├── b.html
│   ├── b.html.br
│   ├── b.html.gz
│   ├── c.html
│   ├── c.html.br
│   ├── c.html.gz
│   ├── d.html
│   ├── d.html.br
│   └── d.html.gz
└── releases
    ├── 20190101
    │   ├── a.html
    │   ├── b.html
    │   ├── c.html
    │   └── d.html
    └── 20190201
        ├── a.html # is changed
        ├── c.html
        └── d.html
```

What is the best way to solve this problem? My worst case scenario is writing a Ruby script which walks to the `20190201` directory and compares the files with the `current` directory. But isn't there a more elegant and faster solution for this problem? Can I solve this with `rsync`, `find` or an other Bash tool? Or some clever directory and file linking?

Comment: `rsync -nva --delete new/ old/` to get a list of deleted and changed files, then process the list ?

Comment: Why not doing all the work with rsync and it's very fast mech regarding delete and sync complete structures. As you wrote, you creating a 'mirror', which is in my expectation a complete view/snapshot of the original source. Why did you not use rsync in the past? Maybe one can help in setting up the right rsync command(s) to update you mirror. We are doing this on many machines.

Comment: Just using rsync doesn't solve my problem of knowing which files I have to compress. The compress part is the part which takes most time.